# Wordpress/youtube video posts

Tags: wordpress-theming

When I try creating a video post for my website, using youtube videos, posts look like a blank white box that says "posted by jerry, July 18, 2011" when my posts are really just youtube videos. I would rather the posts on my site look more like the typical video box that everyone is used to seeing. My website is http://www.AbodeMarketing.com.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you're pasting in the Youtube embed code using WordPress' [Visual Editor](http://en.support.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/visual-editor-tab.png?w=450&h=109) instead of the HTML Editor button which is right next to it.

Simply delete the Youtube code, grab it again from Youtube, edit your post, click the HTML button and paste in the code. You can update your post and your video will show up.

The only gotcha to remember is once you press the HTML button every post or page you edit from then on will start off using the HTML editor so you'll want to switch back by click the Visual button again.

Answer (score 0):

Virgil's right, you're posting your HTML code within the visual editor. To switch, just click the "HTML" tab on your site's Add New Post page. You should be good to go. If your looking to regularly insert videos into your posts, I recommend the plugin Simple Video Embedder. I use it on my tech blog and love it. If you need any help implementing it into your theme just lemme know.